# Honeywell rth9585wf to control Boiler and AC

Tags: thermostat, thermostat-c-wire

I'd like to use a single Honeywell RTH9585WF (Smart Color Thermostat with Wifi) to control an existing radiator system (boiler) *and* existing Central air AC. Existing wiring:
Boiler thermostat (first image) has wires terminating to W and R only.
AC thermostat (second image) has wire terminating to W, Y, G, R, and C.
[Rc|R] jumper is connected in both.

How would I wire both of these to the single RTH9585WF (third image)?

I would have thought simply split the [Rc|R] one for each and then [heat send to W] and [AC send to Y] but the fact that the existing AC thermostat has a W wire connected confused me. Also not sure about the secondary yellow [Rc|R] box on the new RTH958WF. Not that I've extensively researched but doing that now.

Thanks in advance[image: Existing Heat Thermostat]

[image: Existing Cool Thermostat]

[image: New uninstalled RTH958WF thermostat]

Comment: Can you post photos of the wiring at your air handler please?